# EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x18acc41bc) UIIMageView

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting this error when they are trying to add the tap gesture recognizer to An UIImageView in IOS. I am new to this ecosystem by the way, but they want me to fix this in a week xD. I want to clarify that I didn't create this code, but the guy that did left and didn't leave any comments of what is he doing here.

```
@IBOutlet weak var copyImageView: UIImageView!
let tapRecognizerCopy = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.copyImageTapped)) // Here is were it crashes
tapRecognizerCopy.minimumPressDuration = 0.1
tapRecognizerCopy.delaysTouchesBegan = true
copyImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizerCopy)
```

I tried debugging my function but it crashes when I am assigning It and therefore I cannot see what is wrong with it. Looks fine to me.

```
@objc func copyImageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began {
        copyImageView.backgroundColor = uicolorFromHex(0xED6E00)
    }
    if sender.state != UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
        return
    }
    copyImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    UIPasteboard.general.string = self.valueTxt.text
    tokenCellDelegate!.onCopyToPasteboard()
}
```

Comment: Try changing `#selector(self.copyImageTapped)` to `#selector(copyImageTapped)`.

Comment: @rmaddy It didn't work. It crashes exactly in the assignation when I am doing "let tapRecognizerCopy"

Comment: You should remove `self` as other person said, and also initialize `tapRecognizerCopy` inside `init`: when you try to initialize it like this, it has no `self` yet

Comment: Check if `self.copyImageTapped` is nil. Also, remove the `#selector(self.copyImageTapped)`, rewrite it and let autocompletion help you. Might be ``#selector(copyImageTapped(_:))` instead...

Comment: @OttoCheley - comment-out all 3 lines after the `let tapRecognizerCopy =` line, and also comment-out every line in your `copyImageTapped()` func. See if you still get the error.

Comment: @Larme I tried your solution, and works in some builds and fails in others.

Comment: @DonMag I did that, and hasn't crashed but I still need to add the gesture

Comment: @OttoCheley - ok... then add one line of code at a time until it crashes again. That will tell you where the problem is.

Comment: @DonMag sorry I compiled again and It failed in the same line I haven't uncommented one.

Comment: @OttoCheley - are these lines of code in `viewDidLoad()`? If not, where are they? Can you post a screen-cap of the actual error?

Comment: @DonMag I replaced the UIImageView with UIButtons and that solved the issue. Thank you everyone for your support.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of self in your selector try replacing self with your class name, it should work fine.

UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YourClassName.copyImageTapped))